# jQuery and validation error messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
    <div class="QuestionWrapper">
    <asp:Literal ID="litOtherReasonDescription" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    <div class="Question">
    <label for="">Other Reason Description</label>
    </div>
    <div class="Answer">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherReasonDescription" CssClass="txtOtherReasonDescription required" runat="server" MaxLength="250"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>     
    <div class="ClearFloat"></div>
    </div>
```

I have the following markup and I am using jQuery with validation plugin. The problem is the placements of the error messages are shown next to textboxes.How do I control that as I want the Literal text litOtherReasonDescription to be populated with error message.